# Using Intent to move from one activity to other takes alongtime and show blank screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I am showing all mp3 files of my device in recyclerview.On click of item of recyclerview,i am moving to other activity but it shows blank screen for few seconds and then moves to next activity.
Adapter class of my recyclerview is as follos:

```
public class SongsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongsAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songList;

    public SongsAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songList,Context context) {
        this.songList = songList;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view,context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textView.setText(songList.get(position).get("file_name"));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textView;
        Context context;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, Context context){
            super(itemView);
            this.context = context;
            textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitemtextview);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position=getAdapterPosition();
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,FinalActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("NAME",songList.get(position).get("file_name"));
            intent.putExtra("POSITION",position);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

xml of Final Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pritish.sawant.com.musicplayer.FinalActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/finalactivityimageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/shuffle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/finalactivityimageview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@mipmap/repeat" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/repeat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/shuffle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/finalactivityimageview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shuffle"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@mipmap/shuffle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/repeat"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shuffle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            tools:text="Hi" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/finalTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/repeat"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
            tools:text="Hi" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@mipmap/previous"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/rewind"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@mipmap/rewind" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@mipmap/play" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/forward"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@mipmap/forward" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@mipmap/next" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using AsyncTask to retrieve all mp3 files but even displaying mp3 files on my recycler view takes time

Comment: Because lost of mp3 file in your device @abu

Comment: Using asynctask doinbackground@abu

Comment: Can you show xml file of `FinalActivity`.

Comment: i think for accessing mp3 files taking time please wait till all mp3 files loaded and file accessing you should do in background once you get whole data then you update ui thread

Comment: I am doing the accessing through AsyncTask. Even while displaying mp3 files on recyclerview it takes time.  I have updated my question to include xml of FinalActivity

Comment: can you show the FinalActivity xml and code

Comment: Please have a look at the question.I have added the FinalActivity xml

Answer (score 0):

Its because you started the intent in your MyViewHolder class. Try this:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

 public TextView textView;//make public
         View mView;// make a view here


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, Context context){
        super(itemView);
        this.context = context;
        textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitemtextview);
        mView = itemView;//--note-- make mView = iteem view


    }
      //dont set on click listner methods in here
```

}

Now our onBindViewHolder you set the listners here from the holder parameter:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


//--note replace DataItem with your Class/Model/  
final DataItem itemSong = songList.get(position);

    try {
    //this will bind to your recyclerView textView not sure why there is 
    //a string that says file_name should be itemSong.getFileName();
    holder.textView.setText(songList.get("file_name"));


     }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



         //clicking of the recyclycleView 
holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//getting viewholder class and ctor
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     Intent intent = new Intent(context,FinalActivity.class));
            //--note create a static constant string at top of class
            //    public static final String ITEM_KEY ="item_id_key";

            intent.putExtra(ITEM_KEY,itemSong);                
            context.startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

know to recive the intent in your final activity just call:

```
final DataItemSongs itemSong = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(SongsAdapter.ITEM_KEY);
```

From here you can use the itemSong Object and call its properties and set in views ex

```
nameTxt.setText(itemSong.name);
```

Comment: Your SongList object is a hashMap that is empty. Try using the real SongList  object . Can you show me the code for SongList?